# How to map large number of fields(500+) in Websphere Transformation Extender Map node,using Java?

Tags: java, wtx

I'm fairly new to WTX tool.And I have to map 500+ inbound fields with their corresponding names in SAP in very short amount of time.Is there a smart way to do this using Java,rather than dragging and dropping those fields manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm late to  the party, but hope I can provide insight for others...

WTX 8.41 introduced two functionalities that would be helpful here:

- the automapper will generate rules based on objects name. In your case it will depend on the way input and output objects' relate to each other.
- a Java API to the design studio which makes one able to perform any action on a map or type tree from a Java^program.

Earlier versions have the map import/export tool, which make (at least theoretically) possible to generate a XML file to be imported as a map. The distance between theory and practice lies in map complexity, your Java skills, and the amount of reuse this effort would bring.

If I had to make a choice, I'd go the automapper way, even if it meant slightly changing the type tree to have names that would match.

Note there is another way, IF the mapping has to map an iDoc to XML (or the reverse) and tag names are not very important: the type tree could be exported as a schema, and the tool would also generate a map to pass from one format to the other at the same time (and it generates maps for both directiuons).